# Three.js OBJMTLLoader reuse geometry

Tags: html, three.js, html5-canvas, clone, code-reuse

```
    var loader =new THREE.OBJMTLLoader()
    functionality.loader.load('objectpath','mtlpath' , function (object){

       instance[0] = object.clone()
       instance[1] = object.clone()
       instance[2] = object.clone()
       instance[3] = object.clone()
       instance[4] = object.clone()
    })
```

Hi there, I am relatively new to three.js and I have came across some difficulty. I have looked on various posts about clone and meshes and I can't seem to find a solution that works. I have simplified this code to the bare minimum.

If I was to put this in an object and call this 5 times it works great, but it can take ages to render, therefore it makes sense to load the function once and use its properties.

I have looked around to see if I can call geometry from meshes and clone the object but it only seems to load it once. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

If you need more justification please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can anyone provide me a hint to why I can't reuse this object.

Comment: That code should work.

Comment: In theory it should, but I managed to instigate the object on a timer and it loaded the first one, but not the rest. When I removed instance[0] the second object seemed to load. I have done some reading up on this and concluded that it can not be done at present due to some cloning issues. I may have miss understood im not 100% sure. Thanks for getting in touch :)

Comment: You may need to share more code. The problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: Fair enough ill see what I can do :) Thanks for your assistance though